Ubuntu 24.04: after upgrade there is no option to change accent color from orange to anything else
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 from 22.04, I do not see the option to change the color under Appearance. I do not see the list of color dots under the style section as before.
What dconf option should I reset to make this work again?


The solution in the above link should restore all preinstalled software, including accent colors

thanks this helped
